# parameters CI linear mixed model: profile function using lme4 or lme4a

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models

I am trying to calculate the 95% confidence intervals of a linear mixed model calculated with lmer() function from lme4 package. Reading Baker (2010) there is a way to calcuilate the cononfidence interval of the parameters, and it can also serve to create profile plots of the parameters to assess the variability of the parameter estimates (see the book available at: http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/).

I am very interesting in see how the parameters of my model and calculate the confidence intervals. After read some related post answered by Baker the lme4a version of the package could have this library instaled. I have been able to successfully download and instal this library from r-forge and I also tried to download and instal the lme4 packages from the url: http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/

However, I was not able to load the library successfuly. Now when I try to load the library lme4 it gives me the next error:
   *Error in loadNamespace(i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths())) : 
   there is no package called ‘minqa’
   Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘lme4’*

And the next one for the library lme4a:

*Error: package ‘minqa’ required by ‘lme4a’ could not be found*

I am sure that I am doing something wrong, but I am not able to find the solution. Any suggestion will be very welcome! Many thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you need to install the `minqa` package with `install.packages("minqa")`.

Comment: Installing the package I load both packages. When I install the lme4 library from r-forge (.zip), I get the next error fitting lmer: **is.numeric(u <- attr(fval, "u")) is not TRUE** (I have tried with my data and the data of Baker 2010, p8).  If I re-install lme4 from r-CRAN the error disappears, but I continue receiving the error when I applied profile () **Error in UseMethod("profile"):  no applicable (…) to an object of class "mer"**

Comment: There is two new packages, lmerTest, http://www.cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest//lmerTest.pdf, and lsmeans, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/lsmeans.pdf, that can calculate 95% confidence limits, maybe you can look into those? And coefplot2, http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/coefplot2/, I think can do it too...